# Counting cubic congruence modulo powers of $3$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cubics

I am trying to count the number of solutions to the following congruence relation.
$$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+\cdots+x_k^3 \equiv 0 \bmod 3^{\lambda}$$
where $0\leq x_i<3^{\lambda}~~\forall ~i \in [1,k]$

Let $C(\lambda,k)$ denote the number of solutions to the above congruence. I wrote a code to generate some results. It appears that $C(1,k)=3^{k-1}$. $C(\lambda,k)$ seems to be always divisible by $3^{(\lambda-1)(k-1)}$. Is there possible to explicitly find $C(\lambda,k)$ for any $\lambda$ and $k$ without exhaustive search?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The restriction $0\le x_i\le 2$ seems very unnatural when considering congruences modulo $3^\lambda$.

Comment: @GregMartin You are absolutely correct. i mad a mistake in typo. I have corrected it.

Comment: The fact $C(1,k)=3^{k-1}$ is quite straightforward: you can choose the first $k-1$ $x$'s to be anything and then because $x^3 \equiv x \pmod 3$, you must have $x_k = -\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j$.

Comment: @ploosu2 Yeah. For higher values of $\lambda$, is it possible to get closed-form expressions?

Comment: Note that $x_j^3 \equiv 1$ (mod 9) when $x_j\equiv 1$ (mod 3) and $x_j^3 \equiv 8$ (mod 9) when $x_j\equiv 2$ (mod 3). So possible counting algorithm: fix in advance the residue classes of all the $x_j$ (mod 3) (and eventually sum over these choices), and keep only those whose sums of cubes are consistent (mod 9). If $3\nmid x_1$ say, then for any choices of $x_2,\dots,x_k$ there are exactly 3 solutions for $x_1$. Otherwise all the $x_j$ are multiples of 3 and one can divide through by 27 and repeat the algorithm recursively.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I shall try to implement this. I thought we can get similar expressions as those mentioned in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X77900105 for primes modulo $3$ = $1$ and $2$.